# activex controls and scripts running on website

Tags: html

ok so I'm still a complete beginner I've had a few problems and a few successes designing a website, but I want to ad some cool features.

Question is that why does my website always generate the ie message

internet explorer has restricted this site from running activex controls or scripts.

Obviously its because I'm trying to run some scripts, my question is how can other sites have cool features without ie asking me for permission, How do they do it, I don't want my website with zero functionality if someone doesn't allow permission.

thanks in advance, and I'm aware its not a very technical question but really need to know, thanks again.

Comment: Did you add your own site to your Internet Explorer restricted zone?

Comment: no I didn't, basically I'm just beginning and I'm loading them straight from notepad to the web browser I haven't changed anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens is that Internet Explorer imposes several restrictions to scripting in local files.

If you want to develop a web site you'll need to install your local web server sooner or later (Apache or, if you prefer to stay on the Microsoft side, IIS).

You don't find this problem with other sites because you don't load the from your hard disk.

Comment: great I was thinking something like that, I'm setting up a server with ubunti soon, is apache better. hopefully I wont have this problem once its up and running, everything will be run server side then anyway.

Answer (score 0):

a website that is being developed without the use of Internet forever (internet explorer) will ask a question of security permissions. 
after your website is on the cloud server, you will not ask for any of these permits, do not worry too